# Decrypt and read mp3 file directly from CipherInputStream without storing

Tags: java, android, encryption, mp3

I'm downloading and encrypting mp3 files in my android apps. But I'm trying to decrypt and READ the files without writing the file back to file system.  When I try to use CipherInputStream to stream the mp3 to android Mediaplayer API, It cannot recognise the file. However, when I try to to convert to Byte array and stream it as ByteArrayInputStream, it works but I don't want to this because it could take much time for larger files and store the data in JVM.

Here is my code

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
mbuffer = new ByteArrayInputStream(getByte(cis));
Response streamResponse = new Response(Status.OK, mimeType, mbuffer);
```

The above code works fine but the problem with this

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(getByte(cis));
```

in `getByte` method, I convert `CipherInputStream` to byte then convert it back to `InputStream`.

I'm trying to stream cis directly to

```
Response streamResponse = new Response(Status.OK, mimeType, cis);
```

But doesn't work with MediaPlayer

Comment: Can you provide more details about how it "doesn't work" with MediaPlayer? Do you get an error message? A stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I get  MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN

Answer (score 0):

```
         File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("kurchina", "mp3", getCacheDir());

         tempMp3.deleteOnExit();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);

         fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);

         fos.close();



         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);

         mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());



         mp.prepare();

         mp.start();
```